# Use symbolic names without masm32 packet

Tags: windows, assembly, masm, 32-bit

chucks.

I am currently learning the arkane art of assembly language.

I wrote a program that displayed a dialog box (on windows 8.1).
I checked the msdn reference and figured out how to change the optic and behaviour of said dialog box. I also learned where the return value is stored and how to read it. So my question is not of the kind "help me i am stuck".

Look at this little dialog box program:

```
.386
.model          flat, stdcall
includelib      "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Lib\winv6.3\um\x86\user32.lib"
includelib      "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Lib\winv6.3\um\x86\kernel32.lib"

MessageBoxA     PROTO :DWord, :DWord, :DWord, :DWord
ExitProcess     PROTO :DWord

.data
Caption         db  "Masm shizzle",0
Text            db  "Click OK my friend",0

.code
start:
                push    11h
                push    OFFSET  Caption
                push    OFFSET  Text
                push    0
                call    MessageBoxA

                push    0
                call    ExitProcess
end start
```

This worked like a charm, and I figured out how the parameters need to be ordered on the stack.
I then tried to improve the code and make it more readable and cleaner, so I broke the .code section down to:

```
.code
start:
                invoke  MessageBoxA, 0, addr Text, addr Caption, 11h
                invoke  ExitProcess, 0
end start
```

And then I stumbled over a webpage that announced you could make the code even more readable by using symbolic names with the help of "windows.inc".
It said there I would not even need to write functionA (ANSI).

So the invoke call would look like this:

```
invoke Messagebox, NULL, addr Text, addr Caption, MB_ICONINFORMATION
```

The problem is that these symbolic names are from the masm32 package, to be more specific from "windows.inc".
While I am basicly not against using masm32, I would like to know if there is a equivalent file on a "standart" windows host with only Visual Studio installed that I can use.
 
To be more specific, if i would want to run (or even compile) this code on a remote mashine, I could not assume that there is a masm32 installation present on the host, so the includes would point into nowhere.
(as I understand it, or is it packed into the executable if I precompiled it?)

If it is not possible without masm32, then I guess I need to write a symbolic name library....

Comment: The `windows.inc` file only needs to be present when the code is assembled, not when it is run.  And if the end user wants to recompile the code, they're going to need MASM32 to do so anyway.  (Or a compatible third-party assembler, but such an assembler should provide its own version of the include files.)  So I don't think you have a problem.

Comment: Thanks for bringing some clarity into this. So I think I just precompile all versions I should need. For the sake of completition, is there an microsoft equivalent to this file?

Comment: Actually I hadn't realized that MASM32 was a third-party package.  I don't know if there's a Microsoft equivalent, presumably not.  Depending on the licensing, you might be able to just copy the relevant content directly into your source code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the [MASM32 package by Hutch from here](http://www.masm32.com/).
It is by far the easiest way of handling these issues.

It will also handle your ANSI/UniCode situation as described [in this thread](http://masm32.com/board/index.php?topic=4526.0).

Using this package you'd have nothing further to do if you want to use the ANSI version like

```
MessageBoxA PROTO STDCALL :DWORD,:DWORD,:DWORD,:DWORD
```

And if you want to use the UniCode version

```
MessageBoxW PROTO STDCALL :DWORD,:DWORD,:DWORD,:DWORD
```

you'd have to define

```
__UNICODE__ EQU true    ; or any other way of defining the __UNICODE__ define
```

at the beginning of the file (before the includes).

After doing that you can use - in both cases - the following line

```
invoke MessageBox, 0, addr Text, addr Caption, 11h
```